# Sample java code to retrieve AxisFault from InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, invocationtargetexception

My InvocationTargetException prints following when did printStackTrace:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: file.could.not.be.created
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: The File could not be created
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault:file.already.existsFile already exists

The File could not be created
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
```

I would like to retrieve faultcode & faultString from InvocationTargetException: 
  file.already.exists 
 File already exists

how can i do this??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the the stacktrace looks like this and contains no trace of the actual InvocationFailureException, but I assume the AxisFault is directly wrapped in the InvocationFailureException, and then unwrapping it might help, e.g. like:

```
    try {
         // here code which throws InvocationFailureException
    } catch (InvocationFailureException e) {
        Throwable rootCause = e.getRootCause();
        if (rootCause instanceof AxisFault) {
            AxisFault axFault = (AxisFault)rootCause;
            // now extract information, e.g. 
            axFault.getFaultDetails();
        }
    }
```

Maybe you even need to get the root cause recursively if it is not wrapped directly.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, per your suggestion i tried this:

Throwable rootCause = ex.getCause();

if (rootCause instanceof org.apache.axis.AxisFault) {
    
      AxisFault axFault = (AxisFault)rootCause;
      Element[] eleArray = axFault.getFaultDetails();

for(Element ele : eleArray){
         SOP("ele: "+ ele);
         SOP(ele.getChildNodes());
}
SOP(axFault.getFaultString());
SOP(axFault.getFaultCode());
SOP(axFault.getFaultReason());
             
}
But only thing i am getting is: "The File could not be created"
Not able to get faultstring i.e. "File already exists"

Comment: Arf, I have been pretty ignorant of the fact that Axis returns their errors as DOM-elements. If you want to extract the text of the child nodes of the element containing the error message, maybe somethign like that helper over there is useful:  [Extract all text children of an element](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/Extractalltextchildrenofanelement.htm) ... if necessary, rewrite it to be recursive ...